# Trying to get delayed_job 3.0.4 running as a daemon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

So i have delayed_job installed on a production app. It runs fine via rake jobs:work. But when i try to start the script via capistrano:

```
run "if [ -d #{current_path} ]; then cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} script/delayed_job start -n 2; fi"
```

It starts without errors. But if i check `script/delayed_job status` it tells me that no instances are running. Any suggestions?

**Edit**

looks like there is something running (via `sudo ps aux | grep delayed`):

```
 1000      7952  0.0  0.1 112312   832 pts/0    S+   16:17   0:00 grep delayed
```

Output when i run the script:

```
/path/to/latest/release/config/initializers/bypass_ssl_verification_for_open_uri.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant VERIFY_PEER
```

Comment: Can you check if `ps aux | grep delayed` shows the delayed job process? Also, what is the output of `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job status`?

Comment: Edited post with outputs.

Comment: Does anything end up in log/delayed_job.log file? Also you might want to bundle exec all your rake and script calls

Comment: I had checked for that, there is no log file sadly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the permissions on your shared/tmp/pid folder.

Delayed Job won't run unless the user that capistrano is running has has permission to write the PID file into the folder.

Comment: @agmcleod - I still suggest using the capistrano recipe I posted. It hooks into `cap deploy`, so that starting your app server using capistrano also starts DJ (same for restart / stop). You can also use it on its own: `cap delayed_job:start`

Comment: Yep, im still using the deploy script as you suggested. Was a lot cleaner then what i had :).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I start the delayed job demon using capistrano, maybe this will also work for you:

```
require "delayed/recipes"

%w[start stop restart].each do |command|
  after "deploy:#{command}", "delayed_job:#{command}"
end
```

The output of `ps aux | grep delayed` only shows its own process, so DJ is not running on your machine. Maybe this has something to do with your `if`-clause. You could try removing that and see if it start correctly using the `ps aux | grep` commands. The output should be something like this:

```
username    9989  0.0  0.0   7640   892 pts/0    S+   10:54   0:00 grep delayed
username   10048  0.0  9.4 288244 99156 ?        Sl   Jan22   2:16 delayed_job
```

Comment: I gave that a shot, still doesn't seem to be running when i ssh in and run `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job status`. The problem is when i run the above command with start instead of status on the server, it doesnt seem to boot either. No errors appear, but when i check the status, it says it's not running.

Comment: Does this comment help you? - http://8raystech.com/2009/2/28/background-job-processing-in-rails-with-delayed_job#comment-492

Comment: Btw, does starting DJ work when you ssh into your server, cd into the app's "current" dir, and run `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start` from there?

Comment: Hi blackbird. No when i run the script/delayed_job it's the same result. The only thing that has worked so far is rake jobs:work